# Can I use the administrator privilege in windows 7 running under virtual machine in the real computer

Tags: windows, vmware

I was just wondering if there is anyway that allow me to use the privilege of local administrator in virtual machine in the windows7 it self

Example, Can I install a new software that need a administrator credential, using the administrator user in Virtual machine, knowing that the virtual machine is the same as the host it self, Windows 7

Note, I'm using Vmware Workstation 7.x

Regards

Comment: Unless there is a security bug in the virtualization software, having administrator privilege in the guest shouldn't give you any special privilege on the host.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whether a machine is virtual has no bearing on your individual credentials or permissions. From a security perspective, each "machine" is distinct, meaning that just because you are an administrator on the "host" machine in no way implies you are an administrator on any guest virtual machines running on that host, even if they're running the same operating system. Its still a matter of the permissions granted to the login identity used to access each machine.

I hope I've understood your problem correctly.

Comment: +1.  For the record, being an administrator on the host machine does give you everything you would need to *attack* the guest machine, but as you say you don't just automatically get admin privilege on the guest machine, you'd have to work for it.

Comment: my reason why I'm asking this question that when I check the "net use" in cmd, I found __Vmware_User__
why this user is available if I couldn't access it